# How do I find my model id for google assist?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Im trying to set up google assistant on Raspberry pi. I require my 'Model id' in order to try the demo code. I created this earlier but didn't not it down. Is there a way to find it ?

thanxs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [device model API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/register-device-manual#list-model) to query a list of valid models and device IDs. You can access this API through [the device tool](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/device-tool#list):

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool list --device
```